# How Can I build a url from dataframe element?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I have written a generalized function which contains a data frame of two elements team_id and team_name for teams of ESPN website.
I want to write a code which will generate a customized url based on the given team_id and team_name.

```
Example : team_id = 2132 and team_name = Cincinnati Bearcats
```

**Below is the Code here**

```
def get_team_url(team_id, team_name):
   import pandas as pd

   df = pd.DataFrame(['team_id','team_name'])

   df['url'] = 'http://www.espn.com/college-football/team/roster/_/?id=' + df.iloc[0]+ '&team_name=' + 

   df.iloc[1]

    return df
```

The following error i am getting in Jupiter notebook when i am providing values for the functions

When i write an assert function in a different shell:

assert team_url == 'https://www.espn.com/college-football/team/roster/_/id/2132/Cincinnati Bearcats'

Then I get this below error :

**ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define variable like `team_id = 2132` and `team_name = 'Cincinnati Bearcats'`.
team_id is `int` and team_name is `string` now.
then you can pass these arguments to a function.

`def get_team_url(team_id, team_name):
        import pandas as pd
        df = pd.DataFrame([team_id',team_name])
        df['url'] = 'http://www.espn.com/college-football/team/roster/_/?id=' 
        +df.iloc[0].astype(str)+ '&team_name=' + df.iloc[1]
        return df`

I tried and its working fine.

```
>>> team_id = 2132
>>> team_name = 'Cincinnati Bearcats'
>>> def get_team_url(team_id, team_name):
...    import pandas as pd
...    df = pd.DataFrame([team_id,team_name])
...    df['url'] = 'http://www.espn.com/college-football/team/roster/_/?id=' + df.iloc[0].astype(str)+ '&team_name=' + df.iloc[1]
...    return df
... 
>>> get_team_url(team_id,team_name)

                     0                                                url
0                 2132  http://www.espn.com/college-football/team/rost...
1  Cincinnati Bearcats                                                NaN
```

Comment: yes its working but i dont like the arrangement though. and from your output the url is not created, if u click that it goes to nowhere.and also the dataframe allignment is not good..

I want the url as 'https://www.espn.com/college-football/team/roster/_/id/2132/Cincinnati'

Comment: I wanted this and finally got this result , its a bit redundant code but yes i wanted this actual form

Comment: i thought adding to your code will help you. thats why i slightly made changes but rest is same i guess

Answer (score 0):

```
df['url'] = base_url + "?id=" + df['team_id'].astype(str) + "&team_name=" + df["team_name"]
```

Comment: please don't leave code only without any description